# AWS Javascript SDK - Browserify Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat

Tags: javascript, npm, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

AWS JavaScript SDK (v3) is available as node modules.
However, I need to use them in HTML/browser.

Consider the following AWS SDK:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3

These are node modules.
I need to generate a minified javascript bundle for use in html/browser like this:

```
<script src="bundle.js></script>;
```

Specifically, I want to generate bundle for only one of the client node modules there:
aws-sdk-js-v3/clients/client-appsync

I have tried the following:

```
mydir> npm install @aws-sdk/client-appsync 
mydir> npm install --global browserify
mydir> browserify --require @aws-sdk/client-appsync --outfile client-appsynch-out.js
```

However, that results in error message:

```
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'mydir\process'
    required by mydir\node_modules\@aws-sdk\util-user-agent-node\dist-cjs\index.js
```

In general, how do I generate plain javascript bundles from aws javascript sdk v3.
Alternatively:
Is there a CDN somewhere that hosts all these javascript files - that we can directly use?